# Make argument filter in Java

Tags: java

I'm making program that shows revisions. And also I make from and to revision to show. I write in argument which revisions to show.

But I want to make that if I don't write a start revision or the end revision number then it shows default (or it's from first revision or to last revision.

```
about.setStartRevision(( args.length >= 2 ) ? Long.parseLong( args[1] ) : about.getStartRevision()); 
about.setEndRevision(( args.length >= 3 ) ? Long.parseLong( args[2] ) : about.getEndRevision());
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: How to make that if I don't write in arguments start or end revisions number then it takes default number

Comment: Is something wrong with your provided code?

Comment: If I omit one parameter - how would you know wether the start- or the end-revision is missing?

Comment: I'd use named parameters (e.g. employing Apache CLI) and if the parameter is missing, null or invalid use the default. Besides that it should not be that difficult.

Comment: Can you please describe more @user4273614

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [commons-cli](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) and it's [usage](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html)

Commons CLI supports different types of options:

- POSIX like options (ie. tar -zxvf foo.tar.gz)
- GNU like long options (ie. du --human-readable --max-depth=1)
- Java like properties (ie. java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true Foo)
- Short options with value attached (ie. gcc -O2 foo.c)
- long options with single hyphen (ie. ant -projecthelp)